# wiresharkでユニークIPアドレスのカウントの方法について

Tags: network, wireshark, ipアドレス

wiresharkで送信元ユニークIPアドレスの数を調べる方法はありますか？

Comment: この質問は何故「閉じる」なんでしょうか？ 本家の方ですと wireshark の質問もOKなようですが。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wireshark

Comment: 環境及び、自身で調査した内容が乏しいため、解答がしづらいのかもしれません。

Comment: クローズ票は「この質問は、スタック・オーバーフローについてヘルプ センターで定義されている範囲から外れているようです。 」で２件投票されますね。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

```
Statistics > Endpoints > IPv4 または IPv6
```

でタブに総数が表示されます。